# Que problema tiene mi codigo

Tags: java

Dados la categoría y el sueldo del trabajador, calcular el aumento correspondiente, teniendo en cuenta la siguiente tabla:

```
Categoría  Aumento
  A----------3%
  B----------5%
  C----------10%
  D----------15%
```

El código:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sueldo=12000;
        switch (sueldo){
        case 1:
        System.out.println("sueldo*1.03");
            break;
        case 2:
        System.out.println("sue*1.05");
            break;
        case 3:
        System.out.println("sue*1.10");
            break;
        case 4:
        System.out.println("sue*1.15");
            break;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Te sugiero revisar [ask] y [tour] para que, de cara al futuro, tus preguntas sean más completas. De esa forma será más probable que consigas buenas respuestas y más atención por parte de la comunidad

Answer (score 5):

El problema es que estás tratando todo como cadenas de texto literales:

```
System.out.println("sueldo*1.03");
```

Cuando lo que tu quieres es realizar operaciones matemáticas entre variables:

```
System.out.println(sueldo*1.03);
```

Otro problema que tienes es que el uso de `switch` aquí no tiene sentido. ¿Qué significa ese `case 1`? ¿De dónde sale ese `1`? ¿Por qué `1`?

Tu tienes que comprobar el rango de la variable... es decir, hacer comprobaciones "*menor que*" y "*mayor que*":

```
if( sueldo < [categoria B] )
  sueldo *= 1.03;
else if( sueldo < [categoria C] )
  sueldo *= 1.05;
else if( sueldo < [categoria D] )
  sueldo *= 1.1;
else
  sueldo *= 1.15;
```

¿Qué valores hay que asignar a lo que está entre corchetes? Ni idea porque en la pregunta no lo indicas... pero si imaginamos los siguientes valores:

```
          x < 10.000 -> Categoria A
10.000 <= x < 20.000 -> Categoria B
20.000 <= x < 30.000 -> Categoria C
30.000 <= x          -> Categoria D
```

El código podría quedar así:

```
if( sueldo < 10000 )
  sueldo *= 1.03;
else if( sueldo < 20000 )
  sueldo *= 1.05;
else if( sueldo < 30000 )
  sueldo *= 1.1;
else
  sueldo *= 1.15;
```